# If a dictionary value is a list, how to count item in that list?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary

I have a dictionary like this:

```
{'A': ['red', 'red', 'blue'],
 'B': ['red', 'green'],
 'C': ['blue', 'green'], ....}
```

How can I count the items' occurrence in each list?

Desired outcome would be like:

```
A: red 2, blue 1
B: red 1, green 1
C: blue 1, green 1
```

Any tips would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
dict = {'A': ['red', 'red', 'blue'],
 'B': ['red', 'green'],
 'C': ['blue', 'green']}
new_dict = {}

for key in dict.keys():
    new_dict[key] = {}
    for item in dict[key]:
        if item not in new_dict[key].keys():
            new_dict[key][item] = 1
        else:
            new_dict[key][item] += 1

print(new_dict)
```

The output will be:

```
{'A': {'red': 2, 'blue': 1}, 'B': {'red': 1, 'green': 1}, 'C': {'blue': 1, 'green': 1}}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do it as following, using the `keys()` method of dictionaries and `count()` method from lists in order to count the number of occurences for each element:

```
inDict = {'A': ['red', 'red', 'blue'], 'B': ['red', 'green'], 'C': ['blue', 'green']}

for key in inDict.keys():
    print(key + ': ', end=" ")
    print(", ".join([elem + ' ' + str(inDict[key].count(elem))  for elem in set(inDict[key])]))
```

Result:

```
A:  blue 1, red 2
B:  green 1, red 1
C:  green 1, blue 1
```

Answer (score 2):

You can create a `dict` with `collections.Counters`:

```
from collections import Counter

d = {'A': ['red', 'red', 'blue'],
     'B': ['red', 'green'],
     'C': ['blue', 'green']}

counter_dict = { k: Counter(v) for k, v in d.items()}
for k, v in counter_dict.items():
    print(f'{k}:', *(f'{i} {j}' for i, j in v.items()))

>>>A: red 2 blue 1
   B: red 1 green 1
   C: blue 1 green 1
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
data = {
    'A': ['red', 'red', 'blue'],
    'B': ['red', 'green'],
    'C': ['blue', 'green']
}

from collections import Counter

count = { key: Counter(colors) for key, colors in data.items() }
for key, colors in count.items():
    print(key + ':', ', '.join('{} {}'.format(c, n) for c, n in colors.items()))
```

It'll print:

```
A:  blue 1, red 2
C:  blue 1, green 1
B:  green 1, red 1
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works! Can u explain the join and format part a bit?

Comment: And also why the "key: " in count?

Comment: The join is just to put together all the colours/counts in a single line. And the "key: " is for printing the key at the start of the line, like "A: ", "B: ", etc. Basically I'm pulling out the info and printing it in the required format

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, but I mean the key in here: count = { key: Counter(colors) for key, colors in data.items() }

Comment: That's because I'm building a dictionary, using as key the keys from `data` and as values another dictionary with colors as keys and number of occurrences as values

Comment: Actually I understand what the code does but the syntax confuses me. Thank you for your help and patience!

Comment: It's called a dictionary comprehension, used for building dicts in a single line. Note that we can unpack the keys, values returned by items()

Comment: I'll look into that, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using [collections.Counter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter)

```
for key in dic:
    c = Counter(dic[key])
    print(key + ':')
    print(c.keys())
    print(c.values())
```

this will output:

```
A:
dict_keys(['red', 'blue'])
dict_values([2, 1])
B:
dict_keys(['red', 'green'])
dict_values([1, 1])
C:
dict_keys(['blue', 'green'])
dict_values([1, 1])
```